# how to intent specific gallery folder by using MediaStore

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried this code.

```
public static void openGallery(Context context) {
       String bucketId = "";
       final String[] projection = new String[] {"DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + ", " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};
       final Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
       while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
           final String bucketName = cur.getString((cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)));
           if (bucketName.equals("Your_dir_name")) {
               bucketId = cur.getString((cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID)));
               break;
           }
       }
       Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

       if (bucketId.length() > 0) {
           mediaUri = mediaUri.buildUpon()
                   .authority("media")
                   .appendQueryParameter("bucketId", bucketId)
                   .build();
       }
       if(cur != null){
           cur.close();
       }
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mediaUri);
       context.startActivity(intent);
   }
```

But I failed to open the gallery specific folder, but the gallery home screen appears with 'file not supported' Toast.
Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set initial path to specific folder when working with files stored in `MediaStore`.

However, you can use `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` when working with `DocumentFile`, so you can set initial path when user wants to select files from Storage Access Framework (SAF):

```java
Uri initialUri = DocumentFileCompat.createDocumentUri(DocumentFileCompat.PRIMARY, "DCIM")
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, initialUri)
```

`DocumentFileCompat.createDocumentUri()` helps you constructing the initial URI. You can get `DocumentFileCompat` from [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage).